# CukesRunner class not found when running features as debug

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber

I've just set up a new project and I'm trying to mirror a previous, working, project of mine as closely as possible. However I keep getting the below error when I attempt to run my feature files.

My POM and my maven dependencies library have everything I need (I think). What am I missing?

**ERROR IN CLASS**

The import error is: `The type org.junit.runners.ParentRunner cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

The error on the RunWith is: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Cucumber> to Class<? extends Runner>`

[image]

**ERROR**

```
Class not found CukesRunner
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CukesRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>stock-forecaster-api</groupId>
  <artifactId>stock-forecaster-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>     
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>       
</dependencies>
</project>
```

**MAVEN DEPENDENCIES**

[image]

Comment: What is the error in the first import statement?

Comment: @Grasshopper : "The type org.junit.runners.ParentRunner cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
 files"

Comment: pass mouse over red  cross and read any error. Edit this post with the text of your 2 errors please.

Comment: What you do use 2 version (1.2.4 and 1.2.5)?